# Understand flow of execution of Spring framework - add breakpoint to XML file?

Tags: java, xml, spring, netbeans-8

I want to know the flow of execution of the [Spring framework](https://spring.io/).

How can I add a breakpoint in XML SpringConfig.xml files in Spring while debugging a code in NetBean 8.0.2 IDE ?

Comment: XML is no code. You can not use breakpoints here

Comment: You could only put breakpoints into the xml parser code.

Comment: Flow of execution can be checked in spring-code. XML is just a meta data to help spring understand your project structure.

Comment: @Nizamudding: You seem to be a bit confused about how Java, Spring and debuggers work. I edited the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot add a breakpoint to an XML file. The reason is that the XML is not directly executed the way a Java or C or Perl program is. Rather, some other program or library (such as Spring) will *read* the XML file and then process it. This process is harder to debug, because the processing will often happen in multiple steps.

To address your specific question of debugging the flow of execution in Spring:

- The first option is to enable more logging inside Spring - that will show you what Spring is doing (and why, to some extent). Spring logs quite a lot, so this can be very helpful. How to enable logging depends on the logging framework you use, but usually it's just increasing some log level. There are many questions here under the "spring" tag about that.
- If that fails, you can also set breakpoints inside the Spring framework code, to actually debug how Spring is reading the XML, and what it is doing with it. This requires you to have the framework source code - if you use a tool like Maven, this will happen automatically, otherwise you'll have to set it up yourself. This is more complex, but can be necessary for tricky problems.
- Finally, if you get stuck with a specific problem, come back and ask a specific question here :-).

Comment: @Nizamuddin: You're welcome. Consider upvoting or accepting (green checkmark) this answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that's not possible. 
If you have access to the XML parser's code, you can step through that and look at how it parses each part of the XML file.